# Is there a good way to find out or estimate the prices of certain engines?

Tags: engine, cost

I'm specifically looking for the price of a PW150 (5070bhp, Turboprop) and some 55kN Turbofan engine. I'm doing some Direct Operating Cost analysis but I have no idea how much these components should cost.

Comment: With so little information, no, there isn't. There are many other factors, such as qty, new vs used, specific model, maintenance agreement, etc.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer?  That would be the first place I would go for a quote...